# jQuery maths causing random results after i delete the values and enter new ones

Tags: jquery, math

I have the code below. It works to begin with, but when i change the values it seems to keep the previous values in memory and doesnt do the multiplications i want it to. Can you suggest anything?

```
var output = $('#SquareMetres');
$('#input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = parseFloat($(this).val());
    output.text(height*width);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nRAhE/

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your HTML?

Comment: Just added the fiddle :)

Comment: It's not working as it should. Basically it should just multiply the 2 values together, no matter what they are. But for some reason, its multiplying random values from before

Comment: Your selector selects both inputs, not just the one for height. If you fix the first number and change the second one, it'll work. But if you change the first one, the result will be the first number squared.

Comment: Yeah but i want it to submit the multiplication no matter what input the keyup is active on, or have i misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var width = parseFloat( $('#width').val() ),
        height = parseFloat( $('#height').val() ),
        result = height * width;

    if ( ! isNaN( result ) ) {
        output.text( result );
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nRAhE/4/)

Comment: Perfect sir, knew it'd be something simple! Thank you

Comment: If my default values are 0, how can i make it output that before any multiplications take place and if all values are deleted (so the boxes are empty) how can i prevent that from saying NaN?

Comment: Thank you, i'm attempting to limit my result to 2 decimal places, but where should i be adding toFixed(2)?

Comment: Not to worry! Sorted it :) Thank you so much for all of your help! :)